# How can I remove the left spacing between the data and the hidden ticks on the y axis

Tags: chart.js

Image of the problem

[image: 1]

As shown in the image, after hiding the ticks and border on the y-axis, there is still padding on the left side of the data that I'd like to remove.

I'm using the version: chart.js@4.2.1

I've tried the following things:

```
#potential solution 1
layout: {
   padding: {
       left: -10
   }
},

#potential solution 2
ticks: {
   padding: 0,
   backdropPadding: 0
},

#potential solution 3
scales: {
   x: {
    afterFit: scale => {
       scale.paddingLeft -= 3
       scale.paddingRight -= 3
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set the `align` option to the ticks on X axis.

```
x: {
 ticks: {
   align: 'inner'
 }
},
```

See doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes